# jQuery confirm dialog - pause until approved

Tags: jquery

The following code works on buttons and other things that have no default action, but on a `<a href='URL'>` it doesn't wait for the confirm dialog... any thoughts on how I should accomplish this without breaking the pre-existing functionality?

```
jQuery('.confirm').bind('click', function (e) {
    jConfirm(jQuery(e.target).attr('rel'), 'Confirm',  function (r) {
        if (r === false) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the URL on the anchor and have your confirmation do the actual redirect to the "success" page.

You need something like `<a href="javascript:openMyDialog();" >Confirm</a>` instead of the actual url you have now.

Comment: The reason the redirect is happening is because you have a URL in the anchor tag.  You need something like `<a href="javascript:openMyDialog();" >Confirm</a>` instead of the actual url you have now.